# Find value before and after a value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using the `lag()` function to find the value that occurred previously in the same field for any particular value.

Is there a function to find the one next/after the field value?

example data:

```
id     desc
1       line1
1       line2
1       line 3
2       line 1
2       line 2
2       line 3
```

expected result:

```
current   lg_desc      next
line 2    line1       line 3
line 2    line1       line 3
```

the query i have so far is:

```
select  Desc as current,
              lag(Description)  
                over (partition by ID order by TimestampUTC) as lg_desc
        from  #temp1
```

Comment: please show `TimestampUTC` in your sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [lead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function like this

```
select  Desc as current,
              lag(Description)  
                over (partition by ID order by TimestampUTC) as lg_desc,
              lead(Description)  
                over (partition by ID order by TimestampUTC) as ld_desc
        from  #temp1
```